# Combined usage of react useState and useLoaderData throws an infinite Loop error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Initial situation:
I have an element, "root", which checks whether a user is authenticated every time it is called. I'm currently trying out the new React-Router V6 and came across the so-called "loaders". If I now make the API call via a loader and then want to set a variable in the element using useState. I get an infinite loop error.

My main.jsx (where the routes are defined):

```js
import './index.css'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'
import authLoader from './loader/AuthLoader'

// -- route elements --
import Root from './routes/root/root'
import Login from './routes/login/login'


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    loader: authLoader
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />
  }
], {basename: "/"})

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

My AuthLoader.js (the loader function for the API call):

```js
import { API_HOST } from "../config"

const authLoader = async () => {
  return await fetch(`${API_HOST}/auth/me`, {
    credentials: 'include'
  })
}

export default authLoader
```

And finally my root.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { Outlet, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"
import { UserContext } from "../../context/UserContext"

const Home = () => {
  // states
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  const auth = useLoaderData()

  if(auth.success) {
    /**
     * This is not working and throws an infinite loop error
     */
    setUser(auth.data.user)
  }
  
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>  
      <Outlet/>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Home
```

If I insert a `console.log` instead of `setUser(auth.data.user)`, I get the response I expect. But as soon as I try to use useState to set a value that appears in the response, I get the following error message.

[image: Error message]

Can someone help me with the error or at least explain why I get this error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ths is because your component re-renders upon setState, and since your auth.success is always true, you get infinite renders because you are re-executing your condition every time.
Move your const auth and your if into a useEffect with an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** mutate a state during the rendering phase of your component. Also, your component enables putting your application in an inconsistent state; you can call `setUser`, which will make `user` and `auth.data.user` having different values. Furthermore, you don't need to use a state, here. You don't need a `useEffect` either; if you have a `useEffect` only to update a state, you are using that hook wrong.

What I suggest, is to rewrite your component as:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const auth = useLoaderData()
  const userContext = useMemo(() => ({
    get user() {
      return auth.success ? auth.data.user : null
    } 
    logout() {
      // implement this, should invalidate current user session 
    } 
  }), [auth]) // only updates this memo when auth changes
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth.success) {
      // redirect to /login here
    }
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>  
      <Outlet/>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

---

### Update

I would strongly suggest using [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/), something like:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  // directly use the async function you provided in your answer, here
  const auth = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['auth'], 
    queryFn: authLoader
  );

  // create a new async function to sever user connection
  const signoutMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: signoutLoader, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      // re-run authLoader, and update auth
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('auth')
    }
  )

  const userContext = useMemo(() => ({
    get user() {
      return !auth.isLoading && !auth.isError 
        ? auth.data.user 
        : null
    } 
    logout() {
      signoutMutation()
    } 
  }), [auth, signoutMutation])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // if no user, then redirect
    if (!userContext.user) {
      // redirect to /login here
    }
  }, [userContext]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={userContext}>  
      <Outlet/>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the way you wrote it should work. However, I need the negative condition in case authentication fails (redirection to "/login"). Where in your code should I implement this? Unfortunately, I have never used useMemo.

Comment: The first version works fine. The updated version is a bit overpowered for my use case. Thanks you very much.